# Platform event triggered flow not triggering

Tags: platform-event

I have a scenario where I publish platform events using AWS lambda and run a platform event triggered flow in Salesforce. After publishing the event I do get a success response, but unfortunately don't see the flow triggering. What am I missing here?

This is response I see after publishing an event -

```
Result is -{"id":"e04xx0000000001AAA","success":true,"errors":[]}
```

What I am publishing is the contents of a file.

Here is the screenshot of my Platform Event -
[image]

Here is what I see when I publish a platform event through Postman -

{

```
    "id": "e04xx0000000001AAA",
    "success": true,
    "errors": [
        {
            "statusCode": "OPERATION_ENQUEUED",
            "message": "08cce6da-98d0-42ba-ae7d-9b55491c822d",
            "fields": []
        }
    ]
}
```

@Cropedy -

I just tried subscribing to the Platform Event using workbench and published an event. I did see the event appearing there, but the flow still does not start. Here is the message -

```
Message received from: /event/DLC_Response_Event__e

    {
      "data": {
        "schema": "Q_KJnfqZC25CjdKAACNqzw",
        "payload": {
          "CreatedById": "0053S000002EI1HQAW",
          "File_Content__c": "Test",
          "CreatedDate": "2023-12-26T02:08:17.730Z"
        },
        "event": {
          "EventUuid": "48b70f1a-97cf-4048-9ff8-5eb21bb2e047",
          "replayId": 9255319,
          "EventApiName": "DLC_Response_Event__e"
        }
      },
      "channel": "/event/DLC_Response_Event__e"
    }
```

Comment: some things to look into - 1) if you use Postman or Workbench REST explorer to send the platform event, does the flow start? 2) is the AWS publisher actually publishing to the same org that you are looking for the flow to start?; (3) is the flow activated?

Comment: @cropredy The flow does not start, The AWS publisher is publishing to the same org and the flow is activated. I just tried to publish an event using Postman, I have attached the result to my original post. I do see nothing happening. When I publish an event wouldn't I see logs appearing in the Developer Console? Dont see anything over there?

Comment: @cropredy It is so weird that I do have other platform events in the same org that works as expected.

Comment: yes - should appear in debug log under the user that connected to SFDC and published event

Comment: @cropredy, finally the issue was not having the debug logs turned on for the Automated Process. My platform event was only producing system.debug statements.